# Accessing a site via localhost instead of IP

Tags: php, apache, macos

How do i set it up so my php files in my sites folder can be viewed with just the command

```
localhost/
```

instead of the default

```
http://10.0.1.35/~john/
```

the bottom one works fine but where do i need to change it so in my browser i can just enter 
localhost

Comment: Totally depends on your setup. Do you have a local server installed? By default, "localhost" should work (albeit also with the `http://` prefix

Comment: Do you want to see "http://localhost/" or "http://localhost/~john/" instead of "http://10.0.1.35/~john/" ?

Comment: yes that is exacly what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `/etc/hosts`; it should have an entry `127.0.0.1 localhost`. then you can just use `http://localhost/`. you can't just use `localhost/` because that is not necessarily http and your browser may interpret that as a search or something.